# MC7455 sierra wireless PCI not detected

Tags: linux, unix, linux-device-driver, 3g, 4g

Good day every body

I use MC7455 module in linux machine connected using PCI
but when i do : lspci , i didnt find it
and also with dmesg , it is not detected

Is this problem related to drivers missing ?

Comment: Elaborate what the heck MC7455 is? Link to public datasheet is least you have to add. On top of this append necessary information about kernel you are using and perhaps other environment characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

(For those wondering: This question is asking about the Sierra Wireless MC7455 LTE modem module)

Your modem card is a mini-PCI-e card, but that modem does not connect to the PCI bus. The mini-pci-e slot also connects to the USB bus. This modem card connects *only* to the USB bus, so it will not show up with lspci.

Instead is should show up as a USB device.

Answer (score 0):

I have lots of experience with MC7304, assuming MC7455 works similar.

MC7455 has a miniPCIe interface, I assume your motherboard has such interface because you said the modem is connected. Have you installed SierraWireless driver? If not, Linux doesn't detect the modem. At least that's my case.

If you don't have a miniPCIe interface on the motherboard, you can use a miniPCIe to USB adaptor.

Once the modem is detected, for MC7304 at least, I can find modem in dmesg as well as by lspci.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://techship.com/faq/38/

I had exactly same issue with my Qotom Q355G4, the device was not detected at all. It was fixed by putting adhesive tape over pins #23, 25, 31, 33.